# How to resize the DrawableLeft of an AppCompatRadioButton in Android Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

In a Xamarin Android application, I have an [AppCompatRadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html) with the `drawableLeft` attribute set to the `@drawable/person_resized`:

```
<RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/MyRadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Selection 1"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/person_resized"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

`drawable/person_resized.xml` is a layer-list drawable that I used to downsize the `drawable/person.png` image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/person"
    android:width="22dp"
    android:height="22dp" />
</layer-list>
```

When this view is displayed on an Android N emulator, it behaves properly. **But in my Android Kitkat(4.4.4) device the image is not properly sized.**

Here is what I get in Android N:

[image]

And here is what I get in Android Kitkat:

[image]

**What is going on here?**

I have tried the following methods to downsize the `drawableLeft` in Android Kitkat and **none of them worked:**

- [Using a ScaleDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538641/1182189) to scale down the drawable while [making sure to `SetLevel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531592/1182189), this actually allows to resize the drawable but without control; the resized image is always the same smaller size no matter what scaling factor I supply

  - [Getting the bitmap from the drawable, resize it and create a new Bitmap drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149601/1182189), but this makes the image disappear
  - [Using an inset drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320054/1182189), same as using a layer-list makes the image appear in its original size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36868555/6334207

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36868555/6334207) pointed out by [Mahmoud Mortda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334207/mahmoud-mortda), some dysfunction in Android Kitkat is causing layer-list resizes to be ignored.

So basically you have to do it yourself and the following is what I did:

I created two files `layout-v21/radio_group.xml` and `layout/radio_group.xml`, the former will be used with Android devices running at least Lollipop (SDK 21) and the latter will be used for the rest including KitKat.

`layout-v21/radio_group.xml` contains the `RadioGroup` using the resized images via `layer-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/MyRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selection 1"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/person_resized"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

`layout/radio_group.xml` contains a `RadioGroup` with "hand made" labels made out of `ImageView` and `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/RadGroup">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/MyRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp" />
</RadioGroup>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RadGroup"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:src="@drawable/person"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Selection 1"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here using an `ImageView` allowed me to effectively resize the image.

Finally, in the xml layout containing the `RadioGroup` just include the `@layout/radio_group` and the SDK will load the proper layout with respect to the Android version:

```
<include layout="@layout/radio_group"/>
```